# Major opcode of failed request: 151 (XVideo)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer

with gstreamer-1.0 to display video using below pipeline:

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink

generates following error:

X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (XVideo)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  13 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  34

However with gstreamer-0.10, the error vanishes.

I have tested these operations on ubuntu 14.04 & ubuntu 12.04 but with no success.

please help..

Comment: The following pipeline works: 
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! ximagesink.